# GTK Twitter Client

Tags: python, gtk, pygtk

I am learning Python and PyGTK.
I'm trying to write a Twitter client. Which widget is best suited for displaying the Tweets (Timeline). I can do it easily with textview but it doesn't support sub widgets to display users image.

Tried using TreeView but it seems to be an overkill and is too complex.

I'm using Glade

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try Webkit (the browser rendering engine) using [pywebkitgtk](http://code.google.com/p/pywebkitgtk/). It let's you develop in web technologies (HTML, CSS, JS) on the desktop. I think Gwibber, the microblogging client, uses it.

The widget you'd have to use is *webkit.WebView*. I'm not able to post more links here, just google for "HOWTO Create Python GUIs using HTML".

Comment: +1 I think this is easier in the long run, especially since the OP already sees parallels to a TextView, and secondly since theming can be implemented very easily (with CSS).

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest [GtkTreeView](http://library.gnome.org/devel/gtk/stable/GtkTreeView.html), too. I agree it's kind of complicated (especially if you had time with GTK+ 1.2.x to get used to [GtkCList](http://library.gnome.org/devel/gtk/stable/GtkCList.html), which is now deprecated). Still, it's a very powerful API and widget, and you will not regret learning it.

Trees are flexible and easy to use, and you will probably find more than once place where you can use one, so you will get a lot of use out of the learning.

There should be plenty of tutorials, showing the necessary steps.

Comment: +1, I think a treeview would be ideal for listing tweets. It can be hard to figure out but this tutorial helps http://pygtk.org/pygtk2tutorial/index.html

Answer (score 1):

Actually the TreeView does support embedding images and widgets within the text. Checkout the PyGTK Tutorial section on TextView specifically: [Inserting Images and Widgets](http://pygtk.org/pygtk2tutorial/sec-TextBuffers.html#id2855808)